# plot arima by plot function with n.ahead warning in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima

When I plot arima by using plot function with parameter n.ahead, I received the following warnings.
How can I solve it?

Warning messages:

1. In plot.window(...) : "n.ahead" is not a graphical parameter
2. In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "n.ahead" is not a graphical parameter
3. In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
   "n.ahead" is not a graphical parameter
4. In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
   "n.ahead" is not a graphical parameter
5. In box(...): "n.ahead" is not a graphical parameter
6. In title(...): "n.ahead" is not a graphical parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `ts.plot`, and provide the prediction as another time series. For example:

```
class(USAccDeaths)
[1] "ts"

fit <- arima(USAccDeaths, order = c(0,1,1),seasonal = list(order = c(0,1,1)))
prediction <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 6)$pred
class(prediction)

ts.plot(USAccDeaths,prediction,col=c("#ca5116","#f9b384"))
```

[image]